# Positioning of text in input element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a contact form. However, the text in the input field seems to be in the middle of the page and not in the top left of the box.

The text I am referring to is the placeholder "Type Here". Notice how it is in the middle of the page rather than in the top left of the box, how do I fix this?

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  /*Image only BG fallback*/
  /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
  font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}


/*form styles*/

#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: relative;
}


/*Hide all except first fieldset*/

#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}


/*inputs*/

#msform input,
#msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}


/*headings*/

.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form id="msform">
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Your Message</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Feel free to ask any questions</h3>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" class="tafasf" placeholder="Type here" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: you can do it with the padding like instead of 15px  . padding:0 0 80px 0;

Comment: Replace input tag with textarea

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have such a large box for the input makes me think you want text wrapping in the box, and not a single line input. If this is the case then I would recommend using the `<textarea>` tag as it wraps text and automatically aligns the text to the top left corner. It appears you are already formatting for it in your CSS.

Here's the updated HTML.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  /*Image only BG fallback*/
  /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
  font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}


/*form styles*/

#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: relative;
}


/*Hide all except first fieldset*/

#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}


/*inputs*/

#msform input,
#msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}


/*headings*/

.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form id="msform">
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Your Message</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Feel free to ask any questions</h3>
    <textarea type="text" name="twitter" class="tafasf" placeholder="Type here"></textarea>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

To stop the box having the ability to be resized, use the CSS `resize` property and set it to `none`.